# How do I make my pictures be centered when going into full screen mode?

Tags: html, css

So this is a site that has a grid of pics, the h1 goes to the center when I go into full screen mode, but the grid does not. In other words, it is not responsive. How do I make the grid of photos stay in the center when going into full screen mode? Thanks.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title>*****club</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

<div id="banner" align="center" height="50">
<h1>*****CLUB<span>.urmom</span></h1>
</div>

<div id="nav" align="left" width="100">
<p><a href="About">About</a></p>
<p><a href="Contact">Contact</a></p>
<p><a href="Next Party">Next Party</a></p>
</div>


<ul id="pics" align="center" width="750" class="opacity" cellspacing="0">
<li><a href="1"><img src="natasha.png" height="250" width="250" class="opacity"></a></li>
<li><a href="1"><img src="eve.png" height="250" width="250" class="opacity"></a></li>
<li><a href="1"><img src="natasha.png" height="250" width="250" class="opacity"></a></li>
<li><a href="2"><img src="natasha.png" height="250" width="250" class="opacity"></a></li>
<li><a href="2"><img src="eve.png" height="250" width="250" class="opacity"></a></li>
<li><a href="2"><img src="natasha.png" height="250" width="250" class="opacity"></a></li>
<li><a href="3"><img src="natasha.png" height="250" width="250" class="opacity"></a></li>
<li><a href="3"><img src="eve.png" height="250" width="250" class="opacity"></a></li>
<li><a href="3"><img src="natasha.png" height="250" width="250" class="opacity"></a></li>
<li><a href="4"><img src="natasha.png" height="250" width="250" class="opacity"></a></li>
<li><a href="4"><img src="eve.png" height="250" width="250" class="opacity"></a></li>
<li><a href="4"><img src="natasha.png" height="250" width="250" class="opacity"></a></li>
</ul>


</table>
</body>


</html>




  /***********
   Banner
   **********/


   @font-face {
   font-family: blackout;
   src: url('BlackoutMidnight.ttf')
   }

  h1 {

  color: white;
  font-family: blackout;
  font-size: 7em;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  }

  h1:hover {
  color: yellow;
  }

  h1 span {

  font-size: 0.2em;
  }


   /**********
   Grid Template
   ***********/
 ul {
 width: 750px;
 position: relative;
 left: 200px;
 list-style: none;
 }


  /**********
  Pics Position
  ***********/
 li {
 float: left;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 display: block;
 }

 img {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 }


  /*********
  Hover Effects
  *********/
  img.opacity {
opacity: 0.65;
filter: alpha(opacity=65);
}   

  img.opacity:hover {
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

  /********
  Sidebar style
  ********/
 a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-family: blackout;
font-size: 1.3em;
}

p {
position: absolute;
left: 30px;
top: 245px;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
position: absolute;
left: 30px;
top: 360px;
}

p:nth-child(3) {
position: absolute;
let:30px;
top: 465px;
}


p a:hover {
color: yellow;
font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: How about putting this in a jsFiddle so we can play with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to give your UL an automatic margin thusly:

```
ul {
 width: 750px;
 position: relative;
 left: 200px;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding:0;
}
```

Comment: I just tried that, unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: I've just created a fiddle and it did work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/QLxAy/ - I'd suggest going through and removing all the excess code. You don't need position:relative, left:200px; align="center", width="750", etc, etc. There's also a stray </table> tag.

Comment: You were right, I took all the crap out the code and it worked- I appreciate the help.